# Post Question Button Greyed Out

Tags: bug, ask-question-form, ask-question-wizard

I started off using the Question Wizard. When I finished with the Wizard to the point where it gave me a single body for my question, I then toggled off the Wizard and chose to answer my own question. After that, I reviewed my question and answer, and when I went to finally submit my question and answer, the button to submit was greyed out and unclickable.

**Unchecking and rechecking the box at the top to confirm that my answer was for Public Q&A fixed the problem**. It made the submit button blue and clickable.

So my guess is that there's a bug in keeping track of the state of that top Public Q&A button when toggling in and out of the question wizard combined with answering your own question.

Comment: The Public Q&A button is related to users on Teams, though not sure if the bug will go (or worsen) after the domain separation of Teams.